# Afer deploying an express server to vercel, by vercel deployment url, ports are not working

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, server, vercel

After deployment, deployed link's home route works fine. But with different path, it keeps through an error, Cannot GET /pathname in Vercel.

```
// vercel.json

{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
{
  "src": "./index.js",
  "use": "@vercel/node"
}
],
"routes": [
{
  "src": "/(.*)",
  "dest": "/"
}
]
}

// package.json

{
  "name": "tools-manufacture-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "stripe": "^9.4.0"
  }
}
```

The home route is working fine. But when I try to go to another route, for example, localhost:5000/tools, it shows, can not get tools. but it works fine on the local server.